# How to make a call in j2me by using SIP protocol?

Tags: java-me, sip

How to make a j2me application which allows the user to call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it depends on whether target device supports [JSR 180 SIP API for J2ME](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=180) or not

Comment: Can you briefly explain what SIP is about ?

Comment: @AndyFrédéric [SIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_Initiation_Protocol) is API you use to make stuff like Skype. Here's the tutorial if you're interested: [Getting Started with SIP API for J2ME (JSR 180)](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/apis/articles/sip/)